# Customize magento newsletter subscription notification

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, adminnotification

I'm sure this can be done i just don't know where it is, i have had a look to see about it but i can't really see much about it. I have attached the notification what i am on about.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change it in **app/locale/en_US/Mage_Newsletter.csv** file. Remember you only change the second instance e.g

```
"Thank you for your subscription.","Thank you for the subscription."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit that Message by changing in `Mage_Newsletter.csv` file.

**Path of CSV file:** `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Newsletter.csv`

to apply css to message block here is the structure.

```
<ul class="messages">
   <li class="success-msg">
      <ul><li><span>Thank you for your subscription.</span></li></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

to add custom css in magento refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8idAm5lLSg).

Comment: Is it possible to change the styling ?

Comment: @Jake basically it is message blok of magento. if you want to change the style of that it may be apply to all success message of your site.

Comment: That's fine, where is this located ?

Comment: @Jake find the updated answer